# CORS error when using pyyaml with FastAPI

Tags: python, cors, pyyaml, fastapi

I am trying to create a simple web-application using a react front end and fastapi back end. One function of the web-app is the send a file that is collected at the front end and processed on the back end. I have an endpoint on the back end that looks like:

```
@app.post("/upload_file/")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    for line in file.file.readlines():
        print(line)
    file.file.close()
    return {"filename": file.filename}
```

I have confirmed that this code works. From the front end I can send a file, watch the lines print out on my back end terminal, and the front end receives an http response with a 200 status code and the filename.

The issue comes when I try to use the pyyaml library to process the inbound yaml file. Below is a code snippet which does not work:

```
@app.post("/upload_file/")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    yaml_data = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    return yaml_data
```

I get the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload_file/' (redirected from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload_file') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

So this seems to be a CORS issue... My current CORS policy for FastAPI looks like:

```
origins = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

Do I have to add something to my CORS policy to allow it to use pyyaml? I did not think that would be the case since the processing should still be done at the same endpoint (note the endpoints are at the same place), however CORS is clearly not happy about using that `yaml.load()` function. Any suggestions on being able to load yaml files in my back end would be much appreciated.

Per request from Rishabh Batra I have added the OPTIONS headers here: [image]

Comment: can you please check in your browser console the OPTIONS call headers that browser sends to API and add those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Turns out for `starlette`, a library that `FastAPI` is built off, the UploadFile object is not analogous to the python file object. If you want it to behave like a python file object you have to do `file.file`. So for the above snippet which was failing, the correct way to do that would be like:

```
@app.post("/upload_file/")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    yaml_data = yaml.load(file.file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    return yaml_data
```

CORS policy was correct, no idea why it was throwing a CORS error

Answer (score 0):

backend code running on different port  you can use * or defined an all port that use on your app

```
origins = [
    "http://localhost:*",
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
]
```

Comment: Nope, adding the wildcard does not seem to help, this produces the same error

Comment: your application run on a different port   check that

Comment: My frontend runs on http://localhost:3000 and my backend runs on http://127.0.0.1:8000, both of which are included in origins. You will also note that the code runs when you do not call yaml.load() on the same endpoint, so it is probably nothing to do with the endpoint, it is likely something to do with some redirection when calling yaml.load()

Comment: also error and code header show it 307 redirects so the path was wrong something checks into your code.  open console network and see where is request going

Comment: If the path is wrong why would it work when I dont run the yaml.load() line in the backend?